# MySQL Connector/J CallableStatement - Parameter is not an OUT parameter

Tags: mysql, jdbc, callable-statement, connector-j

Attempting to migrate to MySQL Connector/J 8.1.0 and my `CallableStatement` code which works fine under version 5.1.49 fails with:

```
SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_system_setting(IN p_setting VARCHAR(200), OUT message_out VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
  SELECT setting, value, message_out FROM SYSTEM_SETTING WHERE setting = p_setting;
END;
```

Sample Java Code:

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

public class CallableTest {

  /* MySQL Connector/J 8.1.0 (fails on all 8.*.* versions) */
  private static final String DB_DRIVER_CLASS = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";

  /* MySQL Connector/J 5.1.49 - comment line above and uncomment next line to use v5 */
  //private static final String DB_DRIVER_CLASS = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

  private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME?useSSL=false";
  private static final String DB_USERNAME = "user";
  private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "password";

  public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
      Class.forName(DB_DRIVER_CLASS);
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement cs = null;

    try {
      conn = CallableTest.getConnection();
      cs = conn.prepareCall("{call DB_NAME.get_system_setting(?, ?)}");
      cs.setString(1, "CONNECT_TIMEOUT");
      cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR); // <-- Fails here

      cs.execute();
      String message = cs.getString(2);
      if(message != null) {
        System.out.printf("out parameter: %s\n",  message);
      } else {
        ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
        boolean rowsReturned = ((rs != null) && rs.next());
        if (rowsReturned) {
          String setting = rs.getString("setting");
          String value = rs.getString("value");
          System.out.printf("setting: %s, value: %s\n", setting, value);
        }
     }
   } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
     try {
       cs.close();
       conn.close();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
  }
}
```

The above fails with using 8.1.0 and all 8.0.* versions of connector/j

```
java -cp .:mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar CallableTest

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter number 2 is not an OUT parameter
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.checkIsOutputParam(CallableStatement.java:645)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:1717)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:1725)
    at CallableTest.main(CallableTest.java:49)
```

But works with 5.1.49

```
java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar CallableTest

setting: CONNECT_TIMEOUT, value: 10000
```

Tried both named and index parameters. Looked at the Connector/J docs and can't find any references to specific changes with CallableStatement between the versions.

Environment

- Connector/J: 8.1.0
- MySQL: 8.0.33
- Java: 1.8.0_331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a function in this DB schema with the same name as the procedure... MySQL allows the same object name to be used to declare a function as well as a procedure. Seems like this should not be allowed as it is the case with other DBs. Connector/J v5 handles this scenario, however v8 fails with an error message that is somewhat misleading. Opened a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=112447) with Oracle.